# how to prevent deletion of current log in user in JSP page or HTML

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

This is my jsp code with delete button. I dont want to delete current login user.
This is my jsp code with delete button. I dont want to delete current login user.

```
<table border="1">
                <thead style="background: #0086B2;">
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Sl No.</th>
                        <th>User Name</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Email Id</th>
                        <th>Login Id</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <c:if test="${userList!=null}">
                    <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="deleteVal"
                                value="${user.slNo}"></td>
                            <td>${user.slNo}</td>
                            <td>${user.userName}</td>
                            <td>${user.emailId}</td>
                            <td>${user.phoneNumber}</td>
                            <td>${user.loginId}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:if>
            </table>
            <br>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="Delete"></td>
                            <tr>
                           </table
```

Comment: what you have above is a table being created with values from userList collection. it has no where related to delete functonality plus where is the action which is called on click of delete button. i think you are confused

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    <table border="1">
        <thead style="background: #0086B2;">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Sl No.</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Email Id</th>
                <th>Login Id</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <c:if test="${userList!=null}">
            <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="deleteVal"
                        value="${user.slNo}"></td>
                    <td>${user.slNo}</td>
                    <td>${user.userName}</td>
                    <td>${user.emailId}</td>
                    <td>${user.phoneNumber}</td>
                    <td>${user.loginId}</td>
                <c:if test="${user.slNo != (User Id from session)}"> 
                       <td><input type="button" value="Delete" 
                            onclick="delete(${user.slNo})"></td>
                  </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
    </table>
```

Logic is that if `current user ID equals the user ID in the list`, then don't show the delete button.

Comment: This will remove delete button. Now suppose I want delete other user means, what to do.

Comment: It only hides the delete button referencing the logged in user. Other delete button will be shown.